# Customizer - How to get theme mod range value?

Tags: customization

From the customizer, I desire to get the value of a selected range value and display that value, but no luck.  Any advice on the code below?

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'range_field_id1', array(
  'default' => '',
  'type' => 'theme_mod',
  'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
  'transport' => '',
  'sanitize_callback' => 'intval',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'range_field_id1', array(
  'type' => 'range',
  'priority' => 10,
  'section' => 'cta_primaryd_section2',
  'label' => __( 'Range Field', 'textdomain' ),
  'description' => '',
'input_attrs' => array(
    'min' => 1,
    'max' => 100,
    'step' => 1,
    'class' => 'example-class',
    'style' => 'color: #ff0022',
    ),
));
```

and I'm using the following to attempt to see the value in my content....

```
...
$content_mod = get_theme_mod('range_field_id1');
return $content_mod;
...
```

but no luck displaying the range.  This process appears to work for everything else though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the value of the range slider to save and display by changing the `sanitize_callback` value to a custom function that returns an integer value:

```
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'range', array (
        'title'    => __( 'Range', 'textdomain' ),
        'priority' => 45,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'range_field_id1', array(
        'default' => '',
        'type' => 'theme_mod',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'transport' => '',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wpse_intval',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'range_field_id1', array(
        'type' => 'range',
        'priority' => 10,
        'section' => 'range',
        'label' => __( 'Range Field', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => '',
    'input_attrs' => array(
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 100,
            'step' => 1,
            'class' => 'example-class',
            'style' => 'color: #ff0022',
            ),
    ));
```

I defined the simple `wpse_intval()` function outside of the customizer class:

```
function wpse_intval( $value ) {
    return (int) $value;
}
```

I used the same code posted in the original question to display the saved value:

```
$content_mod = get_theme_mod('range_field_id1');
var_dump( $content_mod );
```

At this point, I'm not sure *why* this is happening, because `intval()` seems like it should work.

Mini note: the [Customizer Dev Tools](https://wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-dev-tools/) plugin is a handy tool for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you. it works, but to fully grasp the logic,  I wonder why it matters to place that wpse_intval() outside the class? thanks too for the plugin idea.

Comment: You got it! You could put the sanitize_callback function in the class just as well. Then use this for the `sanitize_callback` argument: `'sanitize_callback' => [ __CLASS__, 'wpse_intval' ],`

Comment: You rock bro.  It works on my end. Many thanks for expanding my knowledge on class development with the customizer!